# Prove $P= 7\,{c}^{4}-2\,ab{c}^{2}-2\,ab \left( a+b \right) c+ \left( a+b \right) ^{2} \left( {a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) \geqq 0$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, sum-of-squares-method

For $a,b,c$ are reals$.$ Prove$:$ $$P= 7\,{c}^{4}-2\,ab{c}^{2}-2\,ab \left( a+b \right) c+ \left( a+b \right) ^{2} \left( {a}^{2}+{b}^{2} \right) \geqq 0$$

I found this from Michael Rozenberg's solution. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704808/prove-a2b2c23-geqq-9a3b3c3).

**My proof**:
$$P=\frac{1}{16} \, \left( a+b \right) ^{2} \left( a+b-4\,c \right) ^{2}+{\frac {5 \, \left( a+b \right) ^{4}}{14}}$$ $$+{\frac { \left( 3\,{a}^{2}+6\,ab+3\,{ b}^{2}-28\,{c}^{2} \right) ^{2}}{112}}+\frac{3}{8}\, \left( a+b \right) ^{2} \left( a-b \right) ^{2}+\frac{1}{8}\, \left( 2\,c+a+b \right) ^{2} \left( a-b \right) ^{2}$$

I’m looking for an alternative proof. Thanks!

Comment: Add please that you are looking for an alternative proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I added, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a+b=2u$ and $ab=v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$7c^4-2abc^2-2ab(a+b)c+(a+b)^2(a^2+b^2)\geq0$$ or
$$7c^4-2v^2c^2-4uv^2c+8u^2(2u^2-v^2)\geq0$$ or
$$7c^4+16u^4\geq2v^2(c^2+2uc+4u^2).$$
But, $$c^2+2uc+4u^2=(c+u)^2+3u^2\geq0$$ and $v^2\leq u^2$ it's just $(a-b)^2\geq0.$

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$7c^4+16u^4\geq2u^2(c^2+2uc+4u^2)$$ or
$$7c^4-2u^2c^2-4u^3c+8u^4\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$7c^4-2u^2c^2-4u^3c+8u^4\geq$$
$$\geq c^4+u^4-2c^2u^2+c^4+3u^4-4u^3c\geq$$
$$\geq4\sqrt[4]{c^4(u^4)^3}-4u^3c=4|u^3c|-4u^3c\geq0.$$

Comment: Is there another proof right$?$

Comment: @knvy144444 it should be, of course.